# Sums of Landau terms revisited

Tags: terminology, asymptotics, landau-notation

I asked a (seed) question about sums of Landau terms [before](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/366/what-goes-wrong-with-sums-of-landau-terms), trying to gauge the dangers of abusing asymptotics notation in arithmetics, with mixed success.

Now, [over here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2803/98) our recurrence guru [JeffE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2803/98) does essentially this:

$\qquad \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \Theta\left(\frac{1}{i}\right) = \Theta(H_n)$

While the end result is correct, I think this is wrong. Why? If we add in all the existence of constants implied (only the upper bound), we have

$\qquad \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \cdot \frac{1}{i} \leq c \cdot H_n$.

Now how do we compute $c$ from $c_1, \dots, c_n$? The answer is, I believe, that we can not: $c$ has to bound for all $n$ but we get *more* $c_i$ as $n$ grows. We don't know anything about them; $c_i$ may very well depend on $i$, so we can not assume a bound: a finite $c$ may not exist.

In addition, there is this subtle issue of which variable goes to infinity on the left-hand side -- $i$ or $n$? Both? If $n$ (for the sake of compatibility), what is the meaning of $\Theta(1/i)$, knowing that $1 \leq i \leq n$? Does it not only mean $\Theta(1)$? If so, we can't bound the sum better than $\Theta(n)$.

So, where does that leave us? It it a blatant mistake? A subtle one? Or is it just the usual abuse of notation and we should not look at $=$ signs like this one out of context? Can we formulate a (rigorously) correct rule to evalutate (certain) sums of Landau terms?

I think that the main question is: what is $i$? If we consider it constant (as it *is* inside the scope of the sum) we can easily build counterexamples. If it is not constant, I have no idea how to read it.

Comment: [This question on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86076/what-are-the-rules-for-equals-signs-with-big-o-and-little-o) is a good read about arithmetics with Landau terms in general.

Comment: From the link you gave, the equality can be seen to be either a subset relation or an "is in" relation (i.e. $\in$).  For $\Theta$ you're just saying it's bounded above and below by a constant.  Why not choose $c = \min(c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_n)$ and $C = \max(c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_n)$?

Comment: @user834: As I explain, you would have to choose $c = \min \{c_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ (which does not necessarily exist) -- it is not sufficient to choose for each $n$ individually. (Otherwise, we could show that every function is polynomially bounded by the same reasoning).

Comment: note that $c_i$s are $\Theta(1)$, they cannot change much as $n$ changes (grows).

Comment: @Kaveh: As the $\Theta$ inside the sum are oblivious of the sum (and $n$) they don't care. The constant could be $i$ for all we know (which would remain constant at $i$, while the variable $i$ would go to infinity).

Comment: no, that is not true. If one wants to be completely formal, one has to specify the parameters, and here the parameters would normally interpreted to include $n$. For example, one will not write $\Sigma_0^n \frac{i}{n}$ as $\Sigma_0^n \Theta(i)$.

Comment: @Kaveh Landau symbols define classes of functions; the name of the parameters are irrelevant. See my answer for my take on this.

Comment: Hang on there, Bucky.  I didn't write any summation with a Theta in it.  I wrote a recurrence with a Theta in it.  Do you really interpret the recurrence "$t(n) = \Theta(1/n) + t(n-1)$" as something other than "There is a function $f \in \Theta_{x\to \infty}(x\mapsto 1/x)$ such that $t(n) = f(n) + t(n-1)$"?

Comment: Specifying the parameters with respect to which the function class is defined is important. My example above shows this. Similarly $O(cn) = O(n)$ while $O(mn)\neq O(n)$, $c$ is a fixed number and does not change while $m$ and $n$ are parameters that change (e.g. number of edges and number of vertices of a graph). Symbolically there is no difference between $O(cn)$ and $O(mn)$, the different way we treat them comes from the information that is suppressed in the notation: $O(n\mapsto cn)$ where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed and $O(\langle m,n\rangle \mapsto mn)$.

Comment: @JeffE The recurrence is (mathematically) the same as the sum, which is simply an unrolling. So yes, I looked at the sum and read it differently. I have to admit that reading it as recurrence promotes the context-sensitive interpretation, but that does -- imho -- not make it *correct*. We can all agree what is meant, but I'd prefer a notation that is also correct, so people unaware of such agreements can understand what is written, too.

Comment: It confuses me that I have to defend my (technical) critique from TCS experts who do not argue formally (afaict), but with weak "it should be clear what we mean" arguments. But then, it also confuses me that my correct (at least no one showed otherwise) answer is downvoted, while an obviously wrong one is not (by anyone but me).

Comment: @Kaveh I agree, but that is (part of) the point: Using $\Theta$ inside the sum destroys this connection. $i$ is no longer a constant between $1$ and $n$ but an abstract variable that goes to infinity. It switched from constant to variable. That's why renaming it is legal and does not do the damage; that came before.

Comment: @Raphael No, the recurrence is *not* mathematically the same as the sum, for precisely the reason you describe!  The recurrence has exactly one Theta term in it, which unambiguously refers to a single function.

Comment: @JeffE: Ah, my bad. *Without Landau terms*, a recurrence of this form equals the corresponding sum. Therefore, unrolling such recurrences is natural, and should be expected to be preserved by any abusive convention, such as "Treat all instances of this $\Theta$ as if they were the same". And you arguably even *did* perform the unrolling at some point, or how else did you end up with $H_n$ (which are defined using a sum)? (It's only unambiguous if there is only one valid/reasonable interpretation. That is clearly not the case here, at least not without assumptions over abuse conventions.)

Comment: @JeffE It seems you are dealing with recurrences in an almost symbolic manner. That's not very intuitive, given that most interpretations (and many analysis methods) treat it as a function/sequence, that is handle the evaluated/unrolled terms.

Comment: _That's not very intuitive_ — I strongly disagree, but I think it's a matter of taste and experience.

Comment: @JeffE: Maybe. In my book, the validity a shorthand should be explainable locally. Can you give an explanation why this symbolic manipulation paired with the abuse of notation is valid, other than "it does the correct thing in the end" (and does it, always?)?

Comment: @JeffE & Raphael: you guys should probably take this to chat, and clean up many (most? all?) of these comments at some point (updating the question as necessary).

Comment: @Patrick87: Right. Unfortunately, we have to wait until the system deigns to show the move-to-chat function. Once that happens, I'll move and clean up. (Even though we don't have Mathjax in chat, which will make some comments hard to read.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I nailed the problem down. In essence: using Landau terms decouples the variable of the summand function from the sum's running variable. We still (want to) read them as identical, though, therefore the confusion.

To develop it formally, what does

$\qquad \displaystyle  S_n \in \sum_{i=1}^n \Theta(f(i)) \qquad \qquad\qquad (1)$

really mean? Now I assume that these $\Theta$ let $i$ -- not $n$ -- to infinity; if we let $n \to \infty$, every such sum evaluates to $\Theta(n)$ (if the summands are independent of $n$ and therefore constant) which is clearly wrong. Here is a first giveaway that we to crude things: $i$ is bound (and constant) inside the sum, but we still let it go to infinity?

Translating $(1)$ (for the upper bound, the lower bound works similarly), we get

$\qquad \displaystyle \exists f_1, \dots, f_n \in \Theta(f).\ S_n \leq \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(i)$

Now it is clear that the sum-$i$ and parameter-$i$ are decoupled: we can easily define the $f_i$ so that they use $i$ as a constant. In the example from the question, we can define $f_i(j) = i \cdot \frac{1}{j} \in \Theta(1/j)$ and have

$\qquad \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n f_i(i) "=" \sum_{i=0}^n \Theta(1/j) = \sum_{i=0}^n \Theta(1/i)$

but the original sum clearly does not evaluate to something in $\Theta(H_n) = \Theta(\log n)$. Now exchanging $j$ for $i$ -- which is only a renaming -- in the $\Theta$ may feel strange because $i$ is not independent of $n$ resp. the sum, but if we object to that *now*, we should never have used $i$ inside the $\Theta$ in the first place (as that holds the same strangeness).

Note that we did not even exploit that the $f_i$ may also depend on $n$.

To conclude, the proposed identity is bogus. We can, of course, agree on conventions on how to read such sums as abbreviation of rigorous calculation. However, such conventions will be incompatible with the definition of Landau terms (together with the normal abuse of them), impossible to understand correctly without context and misleading (for beginners) at least -- but that is ultimately a matter of taste (and ruthlessness?).

It occurred to me that we can also write *exactly* what we mean and still make use of the convenience of Landau terms. We *know* that all summands come from one common function, implying that the asymptotic bounds use the same constants. This is lost when we put the $\Theta$ into the sum. So let us *not* put it in there and write

$\qquad \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2i - 1}{i(i+1)} \in \Theta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\right) = \Theta(H_n)$

instead. Putting the $\Theta$ outside of the sum results in

- a mathematically correct statement and
- a simple term *inside* the $\Theta$ we can easily deal with (which is what we want here, right?).

So it seems to me that this is both a correct *and* a useful way of writing the matter down, and should therefore be preferred over using Landau symbols *inside* the sum when we mean them *outside* of it.

Comment: Consider $\sum_i^n i$. I can define $f_i(n)=i$ (using $i$ as a constant), therefore $\sum_i^n i = \sum_i^n O(1) = O(n)$ by your reasoning, right? But this sum is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @Xodarap: By my reasoning, collapsing the sum like this does not work, because coupling the inner $\Theta$s (which are not coupled to $i$ nor $n$) to $n$ *does* change the meaning.

Comment: I'm not coupling them to $n$, I'm just using the fact that $\sum_i^n k = nk$. (And I suppose also the fact that $nO(f)=O(nf)$.)

Comment: @Xodarap: But you don't *have* one $f$, but one $f_i$ per summand. If the underlying functions $f_i$ use $i$ (as a constant factor), you have to expand that, and the sum ends up being correct. So, clearly, by my reasoning the summing rule you propose does not work as you write.

Comment: If I have a sequence $5,1,3,2,\dots$, each of these are $O(1)$ (provided they don't increase as the series progresses). Would you say that adding $n$ of them will generate a sum $O(n)$?  What's the difference if instead of being constants I describe them as constant functions $f_1(x)=5,f_2(x)=1,\dots$?

Comment: Or are you saying that you have a different definition of "constant"? Even though each term is written as $O(1)$ it should actually be interpreted as $O(n)$?

Comment: @Xodarap: If the sum is supposed to add up to $O(n)$, you have to have a constant bounding all of the summands, for all $n$. If you don't have that, the sum is not $O(n)$. I don't know how to explain the problem differently; the issue here is scoping, essentially.

Answer (score 5):

Looks right to me in the following convention:

$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Theta(1/k)$ is convenient notation for

> There is an $f(x) \in \Theta(1/x)$ (as $x \to \infty$) such that
>
> $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)$.

Thus the $c_i$ (or with the notation in this answer $c_k$) you get, are not really dependent on $k$.

Under this interpretation, it is indeed true that $S_n = \Theta(H_n)$.

In fact, in Jeff's answer, he shows that $T(k+1) = f(k) + T(k)$ where $f \in \Theta(1/k)$, so it is consistent with the above interpretation.

The confusion seems to be arising from mentally "unrolling" the $\sum$ and presuming different functions for each occurrence of $\Theta$...

Comment: Jup, but every $\Theta$ *can* have its own function, and constant. So this convention does only work with context, that is if we *know* that the Landau terms stem from a somewhat "uniform" (in $k$ and $n$) definition of the summands.

Comment: @Raphael: It seems meaningless to unroll and then allow different $f_i$: the constants will then depend on the variable! and it becomes an incorrect usage of $\Theta$, assuming the $\Theta$ variable is $i$ (or $k$ in above answer). Even if we assume the variable is $n$, it is still looks meaningless to me.

Comment: In principle, every $\Theta$ can have its own constant, but **in the particular context you describe**, it's clear that every $\Theta$ does _not_ have its own constant.

Comment: @JeffE: Right. We can have multiple $\Theta$ with their own constants, as long as the constants are really constant :-)

Comment: @JeffE So why don't you just write what you mean but prefer something ambiguous/wrong? Note that my updated answer now proposes a way to do so. I'd appreciate comments on that; downvotes with no reason don't help me understand why people seem to reject my point.

Answer (score -1):

If each $c_i$ is a constant, then there is some $c_{max}$ such that $\forall c_i: c_i\leq c_{max}$. So clearly $$\sum c_i f(i) \leq \sum c_{max} f(i) = c_{max} \sum f(i) = O\left(\sum f(i)\right)$$ Same idea for little o.

I think the problem here is that $1/i\not=\Theta(1)$. It's $o(1/n)$ (since there is no $\epsilon$ such that $\forall i: 1/i>\epsilon$), so the overall sum will be $no(1/n)=o(1)$.  And each term is $O(1)$, meaning the overall sum is $O(n)$. So no tight bounds can be found from this method.

I think your questions are:

1. Is bounding $\sum_i^n f(i)$ by doing the little o of each term and the big o of each term then multiplying by $n$ acceptable? (Answer: Yes)
2. Is there a better method? (Answer: Not that I know of.)

Hopefully someone else can answer #2 more clearly.

EDIT: Looking over your question again, I think you are asking

> $\sum_i^n \Theta(f(n)) = \Theta(nf(n))$ ?

To which the answer is yes. In this case though, each term is not $\Theta$ of anything, so that approach falls apart.

EDIT 2: You say "consider $c_i=i$, then there is no $c_{max}$". Unequivocally true. If you say that $c_i$ is a non-constant function of $i$, then it is, by definition, non-constant.

Note that if you define it this way, then $c_i i$ is not $\Theta(i)$, it's $\Theta(i^2)$. Indeed, if you define "constant" to mean "any function of $i$", then any two functions of $i$ differ by a "constant"!

Perhaps this is an easier way to think of it: we have the sequence $1,\frac{1}{2},\dots,\frac{1}{n}$. What's the smallest term in this sequence? Well, it will depend on $n$. So we can't consider the terms as constant.

(Computer scientists are often more familiar with big-O, so it might be more intuitive to ask if $1,\dots,n$ has a constant largest term.)

To provide your proof: let $f(i_{min})$ be the smallest value of $f(i)$ in the range $1,\dots,n$. Then $$\sum_i^n f(i) \geq \sum_i^n f(i_{min}) = n f(i_{min}) = n o(f(n))$$

An analogous proof can be made for the upper bound.

Lastly, you write that $H_n = o(n)$ and as proof give that $H_n = \Theta(\log n)$. This is in fact a counter-proof: if $H_n$ is "bigger" than $n$, then it can't be "smaller" than $\log n$, which is what's required for it to be $\Theta(\log n)$. So it can't be $o(n)$.

Comment: 1) "..then there is some $c_{max}$ such that..." -- no, there is not. Consider $(c_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $c_i = i$. 2) "I don't think $H_n=o(n)$" -- [$H_n \in \Theta(\ln n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) 3)  $1/i\not=\Theta(1)$. It's $o(1/n)$ -- That is wrong. As $1/i \geq 1/n$, $1/i \in \Omega(1/n)$. 4) "(Answer: Yes)" -- as long as I don't see a formal proof of that fact, I don't believe it. Besides, "multiplying by $n$" is not what happened in the exhibited case.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. Your proof does not work because we may not have the same $f$ in every summand, and not even the same for the same summand but different $n$. I think I nailed it down; I will compose an answer shortly.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're saying, so I'm glad you figured it out :-)