# Why is Heapsort in O(n log n) if not all n operations take time log n?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, sorting, heaps, heap-sort

let's consider that we already have constructed heap array.

so from this, when we do heap sort, the number of elements that have to be sorted decreased. I mean heap decrease.(which also means heap tree level decreases -> **downheap** operation level decreases

but `nlogn` means each `n` nodes has `logn` operation. But not all nodes do `logn`**(original down heap operation level)** operation because of heap tree level decrease.

Comment: Note that it is "$O$" in $O(\log n)$. That is to say, it is an upper bound.

Comment: Recall the definition of asymptotic analysis — as a follow up, could you find a tighter upper bound for heap sort than $O(n \log n)$ knowing it's definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $n \log n$ means each $n$ nodes has $\log n$ operation.

No, it does not. That's like saying:

> \$100 means I sold 100 drinks for \$1 each

Obviously, you could have sold any number of things as long as they add up to \$100.

With algorithm costs it's the same. A sequence of operations taking "time" $\Theta(n \log n)$ means that the "time" costs of all the operations add up to something that behaves roughly like $n \log n$.

Once Landau terms enter the pickture, things get muddled. It's tempting to tread $\sum_{i=1}^n O(\log i)$ in the same way as $\sum_{i=1}^n \log i$, but the former sum [doesn't really make sense](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2814/sums-of-landau-terms-revisited). I recommend you read our reference questions on [algorithm analysis](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844) and [asymptotics](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/846/98) to see how one can arrive at the final result here.