# What is wrong with this solution for $\mathcal{O}({\log({n \choose \frac{n}{2}})})$?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, landau-notation

In [this recitation](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/recitation-videos/recitation-1-asymptotic-complexity-peak-finding/) on MIT OCW, the instructor uses Stirling's approximation to calculate that

$\mathcal{O}({\log({n \choose \frac{n}{2}})}) = \mathcal{O}(n)$.

However, I went through the following steps to conclude that $\mathcal{O}({\log({n \choose \frac{n}{2}})}) = \mathcal{O}(\log{n})$. Where did I go wrong?

First, note that ${n \choose \frac{n}{2}} = \frac{n!}{\frac{n}{2}!\frac{n}{2}!}$. By basic logarithm laws, we get that this is equal to $\log{(n!)} - \log{(\frac{n}{2}!\frac{n}{2}!)}$. From this it follows that:

$$
\mathcal{O}(\log{(n!)} - \log{(\frac{n}{2}!\frac{n}{2}!)})\\
= \mathcal{O}(\log{(n!)}) \\
= \mathcal{O}\Big(\log{\big(n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(1)\big)}\Big) \\
= \mathcal{O}\Big(\log{n} + \log{(n-1)} + \ldots + \log{(1))}\Big)
= \mathcal{O}(\log{n})
$$

So, what is wrong here? I've gone over it for a while and I can't see any mistakes. Plotting these functions, though, I can see quite clearly that [there must be a mistake](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bf(n)+%3D+10log(n);+g(n)+%3D+log(n+choose+n%2F2)%7D+from+0+to+10000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $\mathcal{O}\Big(\log{n} + \log{(n-1)} + \ldots + \log{(1))}\Big)
> = \mathcal{O}(\log{n})$

That is not right. When $n$ is large enough,

$$\begin{align}
\log{n} + \log{(n-1)} + \ldots + \log(1)
&\ge \log{n} + \log{(n-1)} + \ldots + \log(n/2)\\
&\ge n/2 \log(n/2)\\
&=\Theta(n\log n)
\end{align}$$

More precisely, since $n!\sim {\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}}$ by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),

$$\begin{align}
\log{n} + \log{(n-1)} + \ldots + \log(1)
&=\log(n!)\\
&\sim \log\left({\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}}\right) \\
&\sim n(\log(n) -1) \\
&\sim n\log(n)
\end{align}$$

You can take a moment to try understanding intuitively why
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {\log(n!)}{\log (n^n)} = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you. However I am a little confused how you got from the 2nd->3rd->4th steps for the first set of equations/inequalities. Could you clarify?

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out, leaving here for others: the second step comes from the fact that there are $n/2$ log terms before $\log(n/2)$, and $log(n/2)$ is less than or equal to all of them, so $(n/2)log(n/2)$ must be less than or equal to the sum of all the log terms. The third follows from that. However, why are the third and fourth steps necessary? Isn't $(n/2)\log(n/2)$ already $\Theta(n\log n)$?

Comment: Yes, $(n/2)\log(n/2)=\Theta(n\log n)$. I must have been overly detailed. I was doubling details when you asked. Upon with you "isn't" feedback, I just reduced my verbosity.

Answer (score 2):

The last step is incorrect.  $\mathcal{O}\Big(\log{n} + \log{(n-1)} + \ldots + \log{(1))}\Big)$ is not 
$\mathcal{O}(\log{n})$.  You made the same mistake as [What goes wrong with sums of Landau terms?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/366/755).  See also [What is the asymptotic runtime of this nested loop?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14880/755).

Comment: Thanks. That's not me in "What goes wrong with sums of Landau terms?" but I see that it is the same mistake I made.

Comment: @ubadub, sorry, I phrased that wrong.  I didn't mean it was you, I meant they made the same mistake you did (it's an easy mistake to make).  I edited my answer.  Sorry about that!